# How to Add Parameter to data set in BIRT

Tags: java, birt

How to Add Parameter to data set in BIRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the respective button in the BIRT Designer.

If you want to do it from Java, see this code: http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/673-how-to-create--dataset-parameter/